# Firebase's child_change provides too much data

Tags: firebase

I am using the node.js version of firebase. I'm using a ref.on('child_changed') to watch a path full of users, with their own paths. My problem is that I'm getting too much information. Consider these logs, which are merely a console.out of snapshot.val():

```
userRefChanged
{ Name: 'user',
  approvedApps: 
   { '-JCGaWvRuMp1oqikxyCl': 'yes',
     _type: 'yes',
     demo: 'yes' },
  tokens: 
   { '-JKpNYqpsi6rTPSxLSzT': 
      { sessionID: '-JKouK9ziLsVbkGGtRWo',
        token: 'w2ylvaMOX045H673oNZTEPUjJeplz9L4fTRpaVMJWeA' } } }

userRefChanged
{ Name: 'user',
  approvedApps: 
   { '-JCGaWvRuMp1oqikxyCl': 'yes',
     _type: 'yes',
     demo: 'yes' },
  tokens: 
   { '-JKpNYqpsi6rTPSxLSzT': 
      { appID: '-JCGaWvRuMp1oqikxyCl',
        sessionID: '-JKouK9ziLsVbkGGtRWo',
        token: 'w2ylvaMOX045H673oNZTEPUjJeplz9L4fTRpaVMJWeA' } } }

userRefChanged
{ Name: 'user',
  approvedApps: 
   { '-JCGaWvRuMp1oqikxyCl': 'yes',
     _type: 'yes',
     demo: 'yes' },
  tokens: 
   { '-JKpNYqpsi6rTPSxLSzT': 
      { appID: '-JCGaWvRuMp1oqikxyCl',
        rand: 0.8973847175948322,
        sessionID: '-JKouK9ziLsVbkGGtRWo',
        token: 'w2ylvaMOX045H673oNZTEPUjJeplz9L4fTRpaVMJWeA' } } }
```

I would much rather see this as the output, as it represents only the changes throughout the path:

```
userRefChanged
{ Name: 'user',
  tokens: 
   { '-JKpNYqpsi6rTPSxLSzT': 
      { sessionID: '-JKouK9ziLsVbkGGtRWo' } } }

userRefChanged
{ Name: 'user',
  tokens: 
   { '-JKpNYqpsi6rTPSxLSzT': 
      { appID: '-JCGaWvRuMp1oqikxyCl' } } }

userRefChanged
{ Name: 'user',
  tokens: 
   { '-JKpNYqpsi6rTPSxLSzT': 
      { rand: 0.8973847175948322 } } }
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's a question here. It seems more like feedback on the current API behavior.

Comment: The Firebase 'child_changed' event is going to fire any time data within that child subtree changes, and will give you the new state of the child data, not just the diff between the prior and new state, by design.

Comment: But your documentation says otherwise, Rob... "The DataSnapshot passed to the callback will contain the new child contents" (https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/on.html). Well, yes, it has the new child contents, but it has the old as well. Since it has the old data, I can't act only when the snapshot contains the changes I'm interested in. I have to keep a separate copy and compare, or drastically increase the number of on() statements I need to manage.

Comment: @JonThompson - it's not clear from the question but it looks like it's the "tokens" path that is changing. You might want to consider denormalizing your data, and storing token data at a path like "/tokens/$userId/...". This way you can keep an on() statement on /tokens/ without worrying about approvedApps, etc, while still being able to access that via $userId if you need it.

Comment: Actually, this is a normalized pattern. Denormalizing is what I have now.